# Power supply for multiple components

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi

I am building an embedded device where I want to power a Raspberry Pi 4 4G and a LCD display driver. The Pi needs 5V/3A and the display driver needs 3.3V/2A. I have an external power supply, [this one](https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/product/raspberry-pi-official-raspberry-pi-4-power-adapter-netzteil-elektronikzubehoer-gehaeuse-11268330?supplier=406802).

What component do I need that can power both devices with a **single power adapter**? I am looking for a specific board that can give the right amount of power to each one.

Answer (score 1):

> The Pi needs 5V/3A

5V·3A = 15 W. That's a lot!

> and the display driver needs 3.3V/2A

3.3V·2A = 6.6 W

You thus need a supply able to offer at least 21.6 W; adding in conversion efficiency, 24W sounds like a sensible least output power rating.

Since these two devices need different voltages, you can't work with just a single supply. But you could e.g. use a 5V supply for the Pi and 5V->3.3V switch-mode step down converter to get the 3.3V from the same. Of course, you need that to be able to supply at least 2A – so, make sure the datasheet specifies that.

We're not doing concrete product recommendations, but now you know what to look for.